# Custom Session Windowing in Spark using Scala/Python

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

Is there a way to customise the session windowing in Spark using Scala/Python? I want to create session windows based on a user activity stream with a gap duration of 'x' minutes and also, have a maximum window size of 'y' hours. So even if we are receiving events from the same user after 5 hours I want spark to write/submit the session window to some output.

Thank you.

I read the documentation on session windowing but didn't find anything like max window duration.

https://www.databricks.com/blog/2021/10/12/native-support-of-session-window-in-spark-structured-streaming.html
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.session_window.html